# IXMLHTTPRequest2 Remove Cookie - Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am working on a C++ windows phone application that uses IXMLHTTPRequest2 to perform HTTP Requests.  I have run into a situation in my app where I want to remove one of the HTTP cookies that the server assigned to the session.  The cookie is used for authentication, and I want to remove it to force a new logon.

I could not find a method to remove a cookie, and when I tried to overwrite the cookie with a new value, it did not work.

The original value of the cookie was set with the set-cookie header: 
Set-Cookie: XYZ=9c2725ec03169f17345525d5f4f58455e445a4a42;Secure;Path=/

I tried to manually inject my own expiring cookie in this format:
XYZ=xyz;Path=/;expires=Wednesday, 09-Nov-1999 23:12:40 GMT;

However, when the next request was sent, it still used the original cookie sent by the server.  Is there any way that I can properly accomplish this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.  Looks like I was just setting the cookie incorrectly:

```
XHR_COOKIE xhrCookie = {0};
xhrCookie.pwszUrl = url;
xhrCookie.dwFlags = XHR_COOKIE_IS_SESSION;
xhrCookie.pwszName = L"XYZ";
xhrCookie.pwszValue = L"xyz;expires=Wednesday, 09-Nov-1999 23:12:40 GMT;";

DWORD dwCookieState=0;
m_xhr->SetCookie(&xhrCookie , &dwCookieState)
```